# Django | sort dict in template

Tags: python, django

I want to print out a dictionary, sorted by the key. Sorting the keys is easy in the view, by just putting the keys in a list and then sorting the list. How can I loop through the keys in the template and then get the value from the dictionary.

```
{% for company in companies %}
    {% for employee, dependents in company_dict.company.items %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(Just made up the example...)
The part that doesn't work is the "company_dict.company.items" part. I need the "company" to be the value of company. Right now the company prat is looking for a key named "company" not the value of "company" from the loop above.

I'm doing a bit of processing to put the dictionary of dictionaries together. Changing the layout of the data isn't really an option. I figure the right approach is to write up a template tag, just wanted to know if there was a built-in way I missed.

Comment: Any reason why aren't you doing this in the view?

Comment: It's a bunch of processing. And to set it up so as not to have to do anything in the template, would take a second pass at the data. I guess I could just do that... Figured if it were possible to leave as is, it'd be better.

Comment: Django's built-in filter [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) sorts values based on a key but it doesn't sort the keys itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a custom template filter will do the trick.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def dict_get(value, arg):
    #custom template tag used like so:
    #{{dictionary|dict_get:var}}
    #where dictionary is duh a dictionary and var is a variable representing
    #one of it's keys

    return value[arg]

register.filter('dict_get',dict_get)
```

more on custom template filters: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags

in your example you'd do:

```
{% for employee, dependents in company_dict|company %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to modify what you did a bit. My filter returns "value[arg].iteritems()" and the template looks like so: {% for employee, dependents in company_dict|get_dict_and_iter:company %}

Comment: hey whatever works. most people using this site could modify what i did to their circumstance as well.

Answer (score 19):

create a custom filter, which is like this:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        new_dict = SortedDict()
        key_list = sorted(value.keys())
        for key in key_list:
            new_dict[key] = value[key]
        return new_dict
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return sorted(value)
    else:
        return value
    listsort.is_safe = True
```

then in your template you shall call it using:

```
{% for key, value in companies.items|sort %}
      {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

You will be able to get the sorted dict by Key.

Comment: Maybe nearly exact duplicate, but while the other one didn't, this answer helped me and is dad-gum brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: It also helped me more than the previous answer !

Comment: *"Marking a filter is_safe will coerce the filter’s return value to a string. If your filter should return a boolean or other non-string value, marking it is_safe will probably have unintended consequences (such as converting a boolean False to the string ‘False’)."* ([django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping)) So, it is probably better to remove that is_safe line.

Comment: Also, [`SortedDict` is deprecated as of Django 1.7 and will be removed in Django 1.9.](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict). Use `collections.OrderedDict` instead (available [in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

Comment: Tried and tested. Works perfectly! Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This last solution was very useful to me too. I'm using Django 1.6.2, and it seems to be converting a dict to a list with the key as the first elemement of that list and the content as the second. So even when I pass in a dict, it treats it as a list. So I tweaked the above to look like this, and it works for me:

```
@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return sorted(value, key=lambda k:k[0])
    else:
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reasone Turikumwe's filter not worked for me (python3.4, Django 1.7), so I rewrite it to return list of tuples instead of `SertedDict` or `OrderedDict`:

```
@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        a = []
        key_list = sorted(value.keys())
        for key in key_list:
            a.append((key, value[key]))
        return a
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return sorted(value)
    else:
        return value

listsort.is_safe = True
```

So in template we don't need to get `.items`

```
{% for key, value in companies|sort %}
      {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turikumwe's answer got me close, but did not work for my environment: python3 and Django 1.10.

I found that invoking the filter with:

```
{% for key, value in companies.items|sort %}
      {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

actually results in a ItemsView object, not a dict.  (I suspect this is a python 2 vs 3 issue).  Given the ItemsView, the answer is even easier

```
from django import template
from django.utils.datastructures import ItemsView

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
    if isinstance(value, ItemsView) or isinstance(value, list):
        return sorted(value)
    else:
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django's [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) or [dictsortreversed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed).

```
{% for user in list_users|dictsort:'created_at' %}
    {{user.username}} - {{user.created_at}}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for user in list_users|dictsortreversed:'created_at' %}
    {{user.username}} - {{user.created_at}}
{% endfor %}
```